# Troubleshooting Maximum Stack Call Size Exceeded Error in Expo App

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting the infamous Maximum Stack Call Size Exceeded error in Expo app.

I understand that it's caused by code that keeps calling itself, creating an infinite loop.

Does Expo or React Native provide more information about where this error is? I've already been through my code and didn't find anything. Something a bit more specific would be helpful in narrowing down the issue.

What's evn more interesting in this case is that I only get the error in the Expo Go app. When I run the app in Android Emulator, I don't get the error and the app works fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit and it's totally unexpected.

I develop web front-end in React and mobile in React Native. One of the primary reasons is code sharing.

I have a file that contains all the action types I use in managing the state of my app. Technically not but kind of an enum file. They look like this:

```
export const SET_IS_AUTHENTICATED = 'SET_IS_AUTHENTICATED';
export const SET_USER_INFO = 'SET_USER_INFO';
```

In this file, I have exactly 486 action types and this is exactly what was creating the error.

I don't need all of these action types in my mobile app but I'd decided to keep things consistent and I thought this was totally harmless so I've been sharing this enum file in all my React and React Native apps.

Here are two interesting observations:

1. I just started developing with Expo. Prior to that I was using straight React Native -- created through React Native CLI and I NEVER got any errors for using this file.
2. Even more interesting is that the Android Emulator does NOT throw any errors in the same project. Only the Expo Go app throws this error.

This may even be by design and not necessarily an undesired side effect of the Expo Go app. Not sure. I'd love to know if others have had similar experiences with the Expo Go app.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not helpful, but when I upgraded from expo sdk 41 to 43 then I started getting this error. I made no code changes besides the upgrade and now when my app loads I get the error `Unhandled promise rejection, [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.]`. I get the error on expo go on both platforms